# Открывающие и закрывающие теги PHP в HTML

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

Короткие открывающие и закрывающие теги `<? ?>` не рекомендуется использовать в PHP файле. А можно ли так написать в HTML файле? Например, для вывода одной строки:

```
<p><?= $sayHi; ?></p>
```

Или надо использовать:

```
<p><?php echo $sayHi; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Если речь о **файлах**, то в HTML файлах **никакие** РНР теги не работают, ни длинные, ни короткие.
2. Теги РНР работают только в файлах с расширением `.php`. Если речь про HTML код внутри РНР файла, то это все ещё РНР файл, и к нему относится всё что относится к РНР
3. `<?=` это **не** короткий тег. Использовать в РНР можно без ограничений.
4. `<?` короткий тег. Будет удалён в будущих версиях РНР.

Следовательно.

- В файле с расширением `.html` не будет работать **ни один вариант**
- В файле с расширением `.php` надо писать `<p><?= $sayHi; ?></p>`

Answer (score 0):

Здесь есть определённое непонимание, ***.php** файлы обрабатываться интерпретатором PHP который исполняет код обрамлённый тегами PHP, остальное игнорирует. HTML файлы отдаются веб-сервером как есть, то есть текст `<p><?php echo $sayHi; ?></p>` так и останется текстом. А в *.php файле данная строка выполниться и вернёт значения переменной  $sayHi. Формат записи тегов PHP на это не влияет.

Про теги PHP можно почитать [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: да, это понятно. Но как корректно будет в .html файле: <? ?> или <?php ?>. Какой вариант использовать?

Comment: Ещё раз, никак. Если вопрос как писать кастомные теги в HTML, то запись тега PHP (<? ?> <?= ?> <?PHP PHP?>) с точки зрения семантики HTML не является валидной записью.  Если интерпретатор PHP обрабатывает HTML файлы  (что является плохой идеей но настроить web-сервер так можно) то как захочешь пиши. Интерпретатор обработает файл и отдаст web-серверу валидную HTML разметку.

Answer (score 0):

а зачем тебе тег <р> при открытии php? 
файл должен быть в формате php и последний тег ?> можно опускать если дальше ничего нету

Answer (score -1):

Короткие в будущем вам могут создавать проблемы, при переносе сайта например.
Всегда лучше использовать рекомендуемые вещи а не нежалательных.
Правильно:

```
<p><?php echo $sayHi; ?></p>
```